# Add and Remove Filters from an ArrayList

Tags: java, android

I am currently writing an application that takes data from a database and populates an array which is used being used in several places throughout the application for displaying data in a Card View and a Map.

```
public class Filter {

    public ArrayList<Event> eventsList;

    public Filter() {

    }

    public void setEvents(ArrayList events) {
        this.eventsList = events;
    }

    public ArrayList getEvents() {
        return eventsList;
    }
}
```

However I need to be able to allow users to filter that data as currently it returns everything from the database. I have no problem will filtering the data down but what I want to be able to do is have the option to remove filters but not effect any other filters that may be selected.

So for example if someone filters by location and date I want to be able remove one of those filters but the other one still apply and if I remove both then the data set will return to its default "Get All" value.

I am currently at a loss on how to approach this. Is there a simple way to be able to add and remove filters and have everything within the application update without any problems?

Shedding any light on this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: sqlite database? Can you in that case not filter the results with different queries?

Comment: it would be better to filter out the data at database end

Comment: The filtering isn't so much the problem its the being able to remove individual filters without effecting others and having it stay persistent at the same time. So if a user closes the app and then opens it back up the filters that they had before are still in place.

Comment: Why don't you dynamically build a query that is based on the current filters? You can persist the chosen filters for instance in the onSavedInstanceState bundle

Comment: Some of my filtering isn't done through a query however, such as the location filtering. Its done by the user inputting a Location and a search radius which is then processed through geocoding and then it looks through the array of saved "Events" and then pulls out the ones that match the criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would follow this approach:

Create a Filter interface, which all the filters will extend:

```
public interface Filter {
    public boolean filter(Event event);
}
```

Then you extend an adapter, which will store the filters.

```
public class FilterableAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private List<Filter> _filters = new ArrayList<Filter>();
    private List<Event> _items = null;
    private List<Event> _filteredItems = new ArrayList<Filter>();

    public void addFilter(Filter filter) {
        _filters.add(filter);
        _filterItems();
    }

    public void removeFilter(Filter filter) {
        _filters.remove(filter);
        _filterItems();
    }

    public List<Filter> getFilters() {
        return _filters;
    }

    public void setItems(List<Event> items) {
        _items = items;
        _filterItems();
    }

    private void _filterItems() {
        _filteredItems.clear();
        for (Filter filter : _filters) {
            for (Event event : _items) {
                if (filter.filter(event)) {
                     _filteredItems.add(event);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void getItem(int position) {
        return _filteredItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void getCount() {
        return _filteredItems.size();
    }
}
```

Then you create different filters, such as:

```
public class BigEventFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public boolean filter(Event event) {
        return event.getAttendeeCount() > 100;
    }
}
```

or one with parameters:

```
public class NiceCityFilter implements Filter {

    private String _cityName;

    public NiceCityFilter(String cityName) {
        _cityName = cityName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean filter(Event event) {
        return cityName.equals(event.getCity());
    }
}
```

And then you can add them or remove them from your adapter:

```
eventAdapter.addFilter(new BigEventFilter());
eventAdapter.addFilter(new NiceCityFilter("Budapest"));
eventAdapter.removeFilter(eventAdapter.getFilters().get(0));
```

Probably you will have a UI for adding and removing filters, so you have to keep the filter references tied to the correct buttons. For this you could use `View.setTag(bigEventFilter)` / `View.getTag()` for example.

I have showed this example with an adapter because this is the most frequent use-case. But you could change it easily to a plain object which has a `getFilteredItems()` method which returns the internal `_filteredItems` list.

Comment: Yes for removing the filters I have a tag list on my home page that will simply put a small description of the filter such as if they do location it will show a tag saying "Budapest" for example. I think this may be what I need as it looks like it will cause minimal refactoring to my current set-up. Thanks!

Comment: Just out of curiosity what is the EventAdapter that you are adding the filters to? What exactly would it contain?

Comment: If you don't plan it to be an adapter for a ListView, you could just change it to be a class like `public class EventAdapter { }` and remove the override annotations from the method.

Comment: Is there I way I could easily apply the filters so they will work across two different locations? At the moment I have the events showing on a RecycleView/CardView and a Map that plots where they are.

Comment: Yes you could, the RecyclerView uses it as an adapter, and then you write a wrapper for the Map, which just iterates over the list of filtered events. To make sure the map is updated when the data is changed, you can register an observer to the adapter.